# How can I invite a friend to my single player world on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I invite a friend who lives in a different country to my single player world on Minecraft? I have tried going on YouTube to see if I could get help there, but no luck; it was too confusing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

> **Setup**
>
> 1. [Install Hamachi.](https://www.vpn.net/) You want the Unmanaged version, which is free.
> 2. Create a VPN tunnel in Hamachi. (Network>Create a new network...)
> 3. Get your friends to join your Hamachi network. (Network>Join an existing network...)
> 4. Have everyone on the server set the Hamachi network as a Home Network, or allow Minecraft to use Public Networks.
>
> **Host**
>
> 1. Open a single player Minecraft world
> 2. Hit Escape and Select the Open to LAN button
> 3. Set the options and open the LAN network
> 4. Distribute the 5 digit port number that will appear in the chat window to the other players; this can be done over Hamachi's chat
>    window or another chat method.(#####)
>
> **Other Players**
>
> 1. Go to "Multiplayer" on the main menu and either click "Add a server" or "Direct connect".
> 2. Copy the host's IPv4 address (Click on their name in Hamachi and click "Copy IPv4 Address")
> 3. Paste the IP in to the server address box along with the 5 digit port number distributed by the host (#####). You should now have
>    something like ##.###.##.###:##### as your IP. (If there are any
>    letters in the IP, you have the IPv6 address. Copy the IPv4 address
>    instead.)
> 4. Join the server. You should be able to connect.

[Here is the source.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Hamachi_connection_LAN)

Comment: Sometimes hamachi will stop you internet compatability on the device its installed on and have to disconnect from hacachi in the networks tab. I dont recommend hamachi and if you do run into this problem uninstall it

Comment: It's true that hamachi might causes some issues, but it's easy to use. The OP got confused by watching some youtube videos, as he writes in his question. So I thought the best option for him is to share the world via hamachi. If there is a problem with it, he can always deinstall hamachi. (I personally had never problems with it.)

Answer (score 2):

**I think the best answer is the Hamachi one.**

However I will share my experience with the task, it may be useful for someone:

In the past I've moved my single player world to a server and hosted it on my computer or used some cheap minecraft server hosting site.

**Home hosting:**

It greatly depends on the capabilities of your computer and what kind of internet connection your internet service provider provides to you.
In my case I have a static IP address and full access to my home router.

I had to:

- download and configure the minecraft server application
- copy my singleplayer world in the server's world folder and change the server config to use my world,
- log into my home router, assign a static local IP to my computer and configure port forwarding for port 25565 (default minecraft server port) to my local IP
- setup my computer's firewall to allow the java server on the internet
- check my external IP and share it with my friends
- connect myself to the server by entering my local IP (i think the external one worked as well)

As you can see, you need to do a lot of stuff to get it working and there are a lot of things that can go wrong. You can google tutorial for doing all of the steps but if you are not tech savvy I don't recommend even trying it.

**Cheap Minecraft server hosting:**

This is a little easier approach but it's not for free.

Steps are:

- Find a cheap minecraft server hosting. There are some that offer free hosting for a few days. I've paid around 3$ - 5$ for a basic package with 1 GB RAM.
  It should have a server panel webpage where you can configure some of the server settings without having to edit the config file and should also have FTP access.
- Install FileZilla or another FTP client program, use the ftp credentials to connect to the server and upload your singleplayer world folder
- In the server settings (preferebly in the server pannel) change the world name to your world's name
- Share the server IP and port with your friends
- Connect to the server from minecraft by entering the same IP you gave to your friends

As you can see this in this case you don't have to "install" the server and deal with nasty networking stuff and the server config part is easier. Also most of the server hostings sites have a support team that you can ask for assistance. However the server could be far away from both you and your friend so you can have lag issues, also the cheap hosting provides low resources (CPU, RAM..) to the server so it could struggle. I've played with 3-5 people this way and it was ok.